# Programatically add lines to a Super Table field

Tags: plugin-development, craft2, plugin-supertable

I am trying to add new lines into a SuperTable field of an entry from my plugin.
Following the [Developper sample](https://verbb.io/craft-plugins/super-table/v1/docs/guides/developer-examples#programatically-saving-a-super-table-field-with-content), I am able to change set lines to this SuperTable field.
But it is replacing the existing content.
What should I do to be able to keep existing lines in my SuperTable and add new ones?
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Got it!

In case you just want to add lines (or Blocks) to a SuperTable field of an entry, no need to update the entry itself, you "just" have to create new Blocks with correct type, field and entry.

```
    $field = craft()->fields->getFieldByHandle('mySuperTableField');
    $blockTypes = craft()->superTable->getBlockTypesByFieldId($field->id);
    $blockType = $blockTypes[0]; //Only 1 Type of Blocks in the SuperTable
    $typeId = $blockType['id'];

    $block = new SuperTable_BlockModel();
    $block->fieldId = $field->id;
    $block->typeId = $typeId;
    $block->ownerId = $entryId; //this is the entry id

    $block->setContentFromPost(array(
        'categoryOne' => [$catOne->id],
        'categoryTwo' => [$catTwo->id],
        'textField' => 'blablable...'
    ));

    $success = craft()->superTable->saveBlock($block);
```